# json broken after post request

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, node.js, post

I am trying to save a json object in a database. I am using sails as backend and angular as front end.

The JSON I have is valid before calling the post request.

But when I call the post request, the json is broken and only one part of the JSON is sent.

This is the code I sue in my angular service:

```
   GridService.saveTableConfig = function (key, data) {

      var test = JSON.parse(data); // Is correct no errors!

    return $http.post(config.serverUrl + "/admin/saveconfigtable/" + key +"/" + data);
  }
```

Please find an extract of the JSON before the post request:

> "{"prefix":"","name":"Grid","columns":[{"encoded":true,"title":"Line","field":"id","editable":false,"selectable":false,"template":"div style=\"text-align: center\">span class=\"badge bg-cyan\" style=\"font-weight: bold;font-size: 11px;\">{{dataItem.id}}/span>/div>","width":100},{"encoded":true,"title":"Status","field":"status","editable":false,"filterable":false,"width":100,"template":"div style=\"text-align: center\">span class=\"label\" ng-class=\"{'bg-danger': dataItem.businesserror!=null, 'bg-greensea': dataItem.businesserror==null}\" style=\"font-weight: bold;font-size: 11px;\">{{dataItem.status}}/span>/div>"},{"encoded":true,"title":"key","type":"string","field":"key","editable":true,"width":250,"template":"span ng-bind='dataItem.key'>#: data.key#/span>"},{"encoded":true,"title":"keyen","type":"string","field":"keyen","editable":true,"validation":{"required":true},"width":250,"template":"span ng-bind='dataItem.keyen'>#: data.keyen#/span>"},

When I post the JSON, I only retrieve the full JSON below. A part is lost or removed. It seems to be after the #:

> "{"prefix":"","name":"Grid","columns":[{"encoded":true,"title":"Line","field":"id","editable":false,"selectable":false,"template":"div style=/"text-align: center/">span class=/"badge bg-cyan/" style=/"font-weight: bold;font-size: 11px;/">{{dataItem.id}}/span>/div>","width":100},{"encoded":true,"title":"Status","field":"status","editable":false,"filterable":false,"width":100,"template":"div style=/"text-align: center/">span class=/"label/" ng-class=/"{'bg-danger': dataItem.businesserror!=null, 'bg-greensea': dataItem.businesserror==null}/" style=/"font-weight: bold;font-size: 11px;/">{{dataItem.status}}/span>/div>"},{"encoded":true,"title":"key","type":"string","field":"key","editable":true,"width":250,"template":"span ng-bind='dataItem.key'>"

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: The "#" is probably being interpreted as an anchor in the URL, and so the text past that is being stripped from the JSON.

Comment: I suggest something like ``$http.post(config.serverUrl + "/admin/saveconfigtable/" + key +"/" + encodeURIComponent(data));``

Comment: But you'll have to adjust your backend accordingly to decode it when it receives the post data in the path.

Comment: If you're already doing a POST, why not just send the `data` as the request body with the request's `Content-Type` header value set to `application/json`?

Comment: Hey Patrick. Thanks. It works well! mscdex: Would you have an example of your idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks Patrick.

Your solution is good!

```
$http.post(config.serverUrl + "/admin/saveconfigtable/" + key +"/" + encodeURIComponent(data));
```